# Unique Contacts by phone number android

Tags: contacts, android-contacts

How to filter contacts by mobile number like chat applications. If a mobile number saved in contacts database with twice by with country code and without country code. I need to merge two numbers as single contact.

For example, 
  I saved a contact Bala with 9876543210 and +919876543210. In this scenario i need to filter both numbers and return +919876543210 number to my app database.

Comment: if a contact has two **different** phones, do you want two entries on your list? also, if the same phone is saved for two different contacts, do you want two entries?

Comment: No i need to filter single number. If they saved with country code means i need to fetch that contact

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert **all** phone numbers to E164 format (with country code, no spaces or dashes)
e.g: +12125551234

If you're targeting API level 21 and above, you can simply do:

```
String e164 = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(originalNumber, countryCode);
```

To get the country code, try this:

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = telephony.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
```

If you're targeting api level below 21, you can use google' [libphonenumber library for Android](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) with a similar API.

If all phones are normalized into E164 format, you can remove duplicates by simply not adding a new phone to a contact in case that contact already has that phone (you might find [HashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) useful for this)