# How to get the Contact Names of Array of ContactNumbers from Contacts in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I have a requirement when I need to get the Contact name of the selected numbers from the ANDROID_CONTACTS.

I can get the name of a particular number using ->

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

                Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                if (cursor == null) {
                    return;
                }
```

How can I pass a list of numbers and get their respective names?

Comment: You can tell me as long as your code is not querying the whole contacts DB. I mean I don't want all the contacts and then do an if-else condition to get the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the naive approach:

```
String[] phones = new String[] { "(212) 555-1111", "(212) 555-2222", "(212) 555-3333"};

String selection = Phone.NUMBER + "IN (?,?,?)";
String[] selectionArgs = phones;
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur); // dumps the cursor to logcat
```

However, this will only work if you enter the phone number in exactly the same format as it is stored in the ContactsContract DB under `NUMBER`.

The nice thing about the `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` API you've used is that the format of the number doesn't matter, it'll find it in the DB in any format you use.

To replicate something like that, you can try using another field called [`NORMALIZED_NUMBER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone#NORMALIZED_NUMBER) which should always hold the number in a specific format called E164.
So you can run a query like this:

```
String[] e164_phones = new String[] { "+12125551111", "+12125552222", "+12125553333"};

String selection = Phone.NUMBER + "IN (?,?,?)";
String[] selectionArgs = e164_phones; // all phones here must be in e164 format
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

You'll probably need a way to convert a phone number to E164 format for this code, check out [this answer then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493315/819355).